# Copy and Paste row values into next empty row

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to copy the same row of information from a sheet called "Report" (numbers will change), and paste the values into a sheet "Data" that has headers in the first row.

I tried piecing together some code from various questions.

Here is my code:

```
Sub Insert_Data()
'
' Insert_Data Macro
Sheets("Report").Range("B9:F9").Copy
Sheets("Data").Range("A1").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues,
Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False
End Sub

Sub PSData_Transfer()

Sheets("Report").Range("B9:F9").Copy

Dim lastrow As Long
lastrow = Sheets("Data").Range("A65536").End(xlUp).Row

Sheets("Data").Activate
Cells(lastrow + 1, 1).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False

End Sub
```

Comment: In your second macro, how does it not work? Looks ok.

Comment: When it pastes the values, it pastes them in row 59 not directly under the header

Comment: @SJR it works perfectly fine from row 59 down however I cannot figure out why its starting so far down

Comment: Check the value of `lastrow`. It must be 58.

Comment: @SJR yea that's definitely the problem, how can I go about clearing/reassigning the value of lastrow?

Comment: Can you not see anything in those cells? Do you have formulae in them which are returning an empty string so that the cells appear to be empty (but aren't)?

Comment: @SJR realized the table formatting caused the results to get pushed down to 59. So it works perfectly now! Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

You may have to modify this a little bit to work with your code, but feel free to use mine that I'm using in my current worksheet and it works perfect!

```
Sub Insert_Data()

    For R = LR To 2 Step -1   ' Change the 2 in "To 2" to the row just below your header,
                              ' but typically row 2 is the second cell under header anyways
        Call CopyTo(Worksheets(2).Range("B" & R & ":C" & R), Worksheets(1)Range("A:B"))
    Next R

End Sub

Private Function CopyTo(rngSource As Range, rngDest As Range)

    LR = rngDest.cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).row

    rngDest.cells(LR + 1, 1).value = rngSource.cells(1, 1).value
    rngDest.cells(LR + 1, 2).value = rngSource.cells(1, 2).value

End Function
```

I don't like to use the copy method as it's slow and it likes to copy all the extra jargin, where as getting the value is much faster and it's retrieving ONLY the value